# How can I updateMany except one document in mangoose? using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update all  documents except one.
I am using updateMany(filter,doc) like this.
is there a way to exclude particular document in mangoose when using updateMany()?

Comment: well, `filter` is a function parameter that filters out the documents you don't want to be effected. Use it

Answer (score 0):

Yep, but you have to be able to uniquely identify that document. If you have its `_id`, you could do something like:

```
updateMany({ _id: { $ne: idToExclude }}, doc);
```

where `idToExclude` is the `_id` of the document you want to skip.

More info on `$ne`:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/